# QuerytSet raised: related field got invalid lookup :iexact

Tags: django, django-models, orm

I am trying to filter my foreign key and obtain the query set of PhoneOtp model .

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser,PermissionsMixin):
    phone_regex=RegexValidator(regex = r'^[6-9]\d{9}$',message='please enter the correct phonenumber')
    phone=models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex],max_length=15,unique=True)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=15,blank=True)
    
class PhoneOtp(models.Model):
    phone  = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=None)
    otp    = models.CharField(max_length=9,blank=True,null=True)
```

Above are two my models

I am trying the below query:-

```
old = PhoneOtp.objects.filter(phone__iexact=phone)
```

I want to have the query set of PhoneOtp model filtering with the phone number , but it is giving me error for related field got invalid lookup :iexact.
I have searched a lot but not able to rectify this. I am using foreign key lookup for the first time in django ORM.

Comment: I think it should be phone__iexact instead of phone__iexcat

Comment: @hendrikschneider u mean double underscore??

Comment: @hendrikschneider yes i spelled exact wrong in the quesion , error remains same still :(

Comment: Side note: Just like you shouldn't call a person a phone in real life, you shouldn't do it in programming either.

Comment: just as Melvyn mentioned, you somehow messed up with the db. delete the reccords or duplicated rows and try again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
old = PhoneOtp.objects.get(phone__phone__iexact=phone) # or .(phone__phone=phone)
```

the first phone will follow the Foreignkey relation to the **user** object, the second is the **phone** field

BTW, it's better to use **user** instead of **phone** as foreignkey

```
class PhoneOtp(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=None)
    ...

# thus you can get the phone using:
old = PhoneOtp.objects.get(user__phone=phone)
```

Comment: i tried this but it giving error for django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: accounts_user.phone

Comment: @user190549 you set `unique` constraints for `phone`, so you have to use `get` I think

Comment: You wouldn't get that error on a select query only, unless you already messed up your database prior to adding the unique constraint and for some reason it accepted adding a unique constraint (which a sane database wouldn't let you do). So the error you get can't be just from this.

Comment: @minglyu thanks a lot for help!! , i changed the foreign key to user and then query with filter

Comment: @Melvyn , yes you are possibly right , but in my case i think i was assiging the wrong foreign key , it still not works if i make phone as foreign key in phoneOtp table